# Installation of Rserve package in Linux

Tags: r, linux, install.packages

I am trying to install the package  Rserve in R in Linux centos. I added the necessary libraries when configurating the installation of R. But I still get errors and can not install it

```
serve.so RSserver.o Rserv.o base64.o http.o md5.o oc.o qap_decode.o qap_encode.o rsio.o session.o sha1.o standalone.o tls.o websockets.o winembed.o -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lcrypt -L/nfs/home/mnogueira/R-3.4.1/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lR
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Rserve.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rserve’
* removing ‘/home/R-3.4.1/library/Rserve’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpHt0lVG/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rserve") :
  installation of package ‘Rserve’ had non-zero exit status
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Whithout the Rserve package KNIME can not recognize R.

Comment: What is the content of `/nfs/home/mnogueira/R-3.4.1/lib`? Have you tried the rpms availabale via EPEL as per https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/redhat/README?

Comment: There are two files: `libRblas.so`  and `libRlapack.so` only. I dont see any help in the link. I am using local installation and it seems that the link is appropriated for a root instalation.

Comment: If you have to compile it yourself, you should share with us the options you used when calling `configure`.

Comment: I used `./configure --prefix=${r_prefix} --enable-R-shlib --enable-R-static-lib ` as it was suggested elsewhere befor the instalation of Rserve.

Comment: I am wondering if this is a general problem of package installation in R locally, because any package I try to install return me lots of errors of missing depencences, libraries. For instance: `install.packages(c('Rserve', 'opal', 'ggplot2', 'opaladdons'), repos=c('http://cran.rstudio.com/', 'http://cran.obiba.org'), dependencies=TRUE)` . I have been over and over documentations, but still don't know where to start...

Comment: This indicates to me that there is something wrong with your installation; not with local R installations in general. What was the value of `${r_prefix}` during configuration? BTW, I find it interesting that libraries are searched in `/nfs/home/mnogueira/R-3.4.1/lib` but package installations happens in `/home/R-3.4.1/library/Rserve`. Where is `R` installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

"-lR" (which tells the compiler to link agains the R library) should be available with your R installation always. This indicates that there is probably something wrong with your installation.

I found that this can happen if you installed a "ix86 RPM on an x86_64 system" ([source](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Package-compiling-problem-in-Linux-td793690.html)).